# My steampunker won't spawn even with all of the requirements fulfilled?

Tags: terraria-console

I can't make the steam punker move into my house! Even though i killed a mechanical boss, removed the Hallow from my house, and the house is suitable, she isn't moving in. Could someone please help me? I just don't know what went wrong!

Comment: Can you provide more information like what version you use and preferably a screenshot so we can see your house

Comment: im using cosole and i cant put a picture of my house

Comment: This and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198748/terraria-steampunker are duplicates of each other, but I can't flag them appropriately since neither has an upvoted answer.

Comment: Make sure your house has walls that you placed, and no corruption blocks are near. I think it is 50 block limit. Not sure

Answer (score 1):

The house should be at least 10 block wide by 6 blocks tall, it should have any material wall type, example being woodwall, stonewall etc. you need reasonable lighting (at 6x10 1 either end of the house will do), a door, a flat surface example being a piano, table, workbench etc. Once you've met this criteria any cpu can move in. Excluding the Mushroom NPC. I am pretty sure you must kill skeletron prime first though.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to kill one mechanicaal boss. Also try breaking ONE block of the house and outting it back or just altogether make a new house and see if she moves in?

Comment: the asker already mentioned that he killed a mechanical boss