# Terraria Steampunker

Tags: terraria-console

On Terraria Console Version I killed The Twins And destroyer.

But! the Steampunker NPC Wont move in, I do have Jungle, Normal, Hallow in my house, how ?

What am I doing wrong? 
What went wrong?  
Is it only for PC version?

Comment: Are you playing on the console version?  If so, why did you include the iOS and terraria-mobile tags?

Answer (score 0):

You have to defeat skeletron prime also then she will move in.

Comment: The requirement to make the [Steampunker](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Steampunker) appear is to defeat *one* mechanical boss, not three.